# C++ regex to extract variables from a scripting file

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

So I have a scripted file in which some variables are assigned using the # sign, followed by the assignment operator (=), and then a string.  All of this is without spaces.  Sometimes, there will be a comment (starting with the ! symbol) or some extra whitespace.  For example:

```
#mat=3     !mat denotes a material number
```

I want to use C++'s regex utility to extract '#mat' and '3'.  I couldn't figure out the regex pattern.  Even if I had a pattern, I didn't know how to extract '#mat' and '3' specifically from that line.  When I would use cout for the smatch array of regex_search, I would get the entire line.

Any suggestions?  I would greatly appreciate your help/advice.

Comment: So the value never includes a space?

Comment: `std::regex e{R"~((#[^=]+)=(\S+))~"};` <- that might work (with `std::regex_search(s, m, e)`.

Comment: Yes it did!  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, for lines that have comments, regex_match returns false.  How would I be able to trim everything after assignment?  And what if I do I have a space between the equals sign and variable name/value?  Would I just add something like (\s?), resulting in "~((#[^=]+)=(\s?)(\S+))~"?  Also what is the purpose of the tilde signs and the 'R' before the regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "#mat=3     !mat denotes a material number";
    std::regex rgx("#(\\w+)=(\\d+)");
    std::smatch match;

    if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx))
        std::cout  << match[1]<<"  "<<match[2]<< '\n';
}
```

Group 0 represent the whole regex: `#(\\w+)=(\\d+)`

Group 1, 2 represent the first and second subgroups of regex: `(\\w+)` and `(\\d+)`

So `match[0]` will return the first match of regex, while `match[1]` will return the 1st subgroup of regex which is `(\\w+)` and `match[2]` will return the 2nd subgroup of regex which is `(\\d+)`

`\\d+` means match till the last occurrence of digit in word.

Output is `mat  3`.

Compiled using c++14.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit how your code works? It may appear trivial to you but OP propably needs some hints. E. g. explain how groups work. Thanks!

Comment: added  explanation and   also  edited code to according to question than my general code .

Comment: I should add that the value assigned to a variable in this file won't always be numeric.

Comment: okay then replace `\\d+` with `\\w+`  then it will handle [A-Za-z0-9_]  words. more about regx at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes